# How do I add Mark all / Unmark all button in inlineeditor type sublist netsuite

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, suite

I am trying to add a Mark all/Unmark all button in sub-list which is a type of inline-editor sub-list. below I have added a code for list type sub-list which will not work on inline-editor sub-list. Can anyone help to find this?

```
function button1Func(type) {
if (type=='edit' || 'view')
    {
        var record =  nlapiLoadRecord(nlapiGetRecordType(), nlapiGetRecordId());
        var intCount = record.getLineItemCount('item');
        var headrow = document.getElementById("item_headerrow");
        var head = headrow.insertCell(0);
        head.innerHTML ="Select";
        for (var rep = 1; rep <= intCount; rep++)
            {
                var row = document.getElementById("item_row_"+rep);
                var x = row.insertCell(0);
                var newCheckbox = document.createElement("INPUT");
                newCheckbox.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
                newCheckbox.setAttribute("id", "select_CheckBox"+rep);
                x.appendChild(newCheckbox);
            }
    }
 }

function button2Func(type) {
if (type=='edit' || 'view')
    {
        var record =  nlapiLoadRecord(nlapiGetRecordType(), nlapiGetRecordId());
        var intCount = record.getLineItemCount('item');
        for (var rep = 1; rep <= intCount; rep++)
            {
                var repId = record.getLineItemValue('item', 'item', rep);
                if(document.getElementById("select_CheckBox"+rep).checked==true){
                    makecopyfun(repId);
                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        alert("Success");
    }
}

 function makecopyfun(repId){
   var record =  nlapiLoadRecord(nlapiGetRecordType(), nlapiGetRecordId());
  var intCount = record.getLineItemCount('item');
  record.insertLineItem('item',intCount + 1);
  alert (intCount);
  record.setCurrentLineItemValue('item','item',repId);
  record.commitLineItem('item');
  var id = nlapiSubmitRecord(record, true);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure through the API because there's no record object, you could try using jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

First write following code & create userEvent script and apply function name(initnoload) in beforeLoad Event.
Then Deploy that script on Quote.

```
function initonload(type, form, request) {
if (type=='edit' || type=='view') {

    var list = form.getSubList("item");
    list.addButton('custpage_markmark','Mark all','markall();');  //markall(); is function name from the client script
    list.addButton('custpage_unmarkmark','Unmark all','unmarkall();'); //unmarkall(); is function name from client script
    form.setScript('customscript_mark_all_item_quote'); // 'customscript_mark_all_item_quote' is the ID of script

 }
}
```

Above code will add two buttons to Sublist and their action get executed in client script whose ScriptId we have Defined.

Now write the following code & create client script.(Note: Just save the client script, Don't specify any event function name and do not deploy it).

```
function markall() {

    var count=nlapiGetLineItemCount('item'); //gets the count of lines
    for(var i=1;i<=count;i++) {
        nlapiSelectLineItem('item',i);
        nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item','custcol_checkbox_field','T',true,true); //'custcol_checkbox_field' is checkbox's field ID.
    }
    nlapiCommitLineItem('item');
}
function unmarkall() {

    var count=nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');
    for(var i=1;i<=count;i++) {
        nlapiSelectLineItem('item',i);
        nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('item','custcol_checkbox_field','F',true,true); //'custcol_checkbox_field' is checkbox's field ID.
    }
    nlapiCommitLineItem('item');
}
```

After saving the client script please paste it's ID in user event's form.setScript('Client script ID'). function

i hope this will help you out.

Please let me know if u face any difficulty.

Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the help. i got this working last day. but i was doing this in a different way. I was creating a checkbox using JavaScript and giving a select option for the customer. now i can able to select the check box and copy the lines to the end of the list. the problem i am facing now is, it is only updating when i refresh the webpage, if i save the record without refreshing it the committed items are not updating. i will add my code at the question, please advise me how can i do this without refreshing the page. @user6291223

Comment: Yes what you are saying is correct. In this case, you are loading the record, doing changes as selecting line and then submitting record.
Lets say this is the back-end process which you are performing. Now When you load the record initially the page shows that lines were not selected, but as you are loading and selecting lines this process saves the record with changes but you WEB Page still shows the loaded page....
You already made changes but to see those you have to reload the page which help you to get the new values from the record.

Comment: If you want to refresh the current page after your button's performance i suggest you to go through the suitelet which helps you to reload the page.
Please let me know this help or not.

Comment: Can i get an example for this please or any reference . thanks in advance @user6291223

Comment: Hello i was searching for an answer for this. can you help me @UDAY

Answer (score 0):

I do came up with other idea as you can use the field which'll help you to mark/unmark all lines under sublist..you can add subtab to the form and under subtab you can add field and sublist. later you can apply script on that field which will help you to mark/unmark all sublist lines.

Here is the code...

form.addSubTab('custpage_tab', 'Main Tab');
form.addField('custpage_chkmark','checkbox','Mark/Unmark All',null,'custpage_tab');
            form.addSubList('custpage_sublst','inlineeditor','SampleSubList','custpage_tab');

Comment: I can't create a new sub-list. I have to implement this on ITEM list in a quotation module. What you are talking about is a new sub-list. In that case we can use addMarkAllButtons(); API to create this option. please help me if you know how to add markAll button on inline-editor sub-list. @user6291223

Comment: alright we have to do some more work on it...please follow the below answer for it..m writing it in detail.